# Simple Animation in Cocoa Objective-C

Tags: cocoa, animation

I have written a simple animation for an iOS game and I am trying to convert it for Mac OS.

Here is my code for iOS

```
NSMutableArray *imgArr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    for(int i = 1; i < 6 + 1; i++) {
        [imgArr addObject: [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png", filePrefix, i]]];
    }

    UIImageView * animation = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    animation.animationImages = imgArr;

    animation.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [animation startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:animation];
```

As for cocoa, this part gives errors.. How can I fix this?

```
//animation.animationImages = imgArr;

//animation.animationRepeatCount = 1;
//[animation startAnimating];
```

New code with timer

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(anim)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];


- (void)anim {
    ++num;


    NSImageView *animation = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(shipPosition.x, shipPosition.y, shipSize.width, shipSize.height)];

    [animation setImage: [NSImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"explosprite%d.png", num]] ];
    [objectView addSubview:animation];

    [animation release];
}
```

Comment: I just answered [another question with essentially the same goal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14064328/30461). (By the way, you know your code creates a new NSImageView every frame and doesn't clean up the old ones, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageView does not exist in Cocoa at all. Cocoa does not really have support for sprite animation like you're trying to do here. The most common way AFAIK is just to set an NSTimer and update the image appropriately when the timer fires.

You could also create a custom CALayer subclass that handles animating images. I'm not sure that's necessarily easier, but it's an option.

Comment: @user1526474 Unfortunately not. NSImageView is from a more primitive time.

Comment: I have tried the following code but it doesnt really animate.. it just shows the last image.. `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(anim)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
`